# Why is upcasting a Class considered an unsafe operation?

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

Why does the Java compiler trigger an "unchecked cast" warning when casting `Class<? extends Object>` to `Class<Object>`? How could this cast possibly fail?

Comment: This is because `Class<Object>` is not the parent of, for example, `Class<String>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: How so? `String` extends `Object`. I understand that the compiler would want to prevent me from casting `List<String>` to `List<Object>` because then I'd be allowed to insert non-Strings into the list, but in the cast of `Class` there is no danger. Are you saying that the language authors wanted to avoid special treatment for safe classes like `Class` so they forbid this across the board?

Comment: I am saying that casting a wildcard type to a concrete type is always unsafe. You cannot use a `Class<String>` where a `Class<Object>` is required because Java does not treat one as the parent of the other. You cannot pass a `Class<Object>` to a method that takes a `Class<String>` so by casting you are potentially allowing behaviour that would not be allowed with the wildcard type.

Comment: @Gili: If you are claiming that it is "safe" because `Class` is a producer, then you should always be using a wildcard-parameterized `Class` type -- there would be no reason ever to cast it to `Class<Object>`.

Comment: @newacct: I need to pass two `Class<?>` variables into a method that requires their captures to be the same. I believe using `Class<Object>` is the only solution for that. I am familiar with the "private helper method for wildcard capture" from the Effective Java book, page 140, but I don't think it works for this case.

Comment: @Gili: But what operation could you possibly do that will compile for two `Class<T>` and will not compile for two `Class<? extends T>`?

Comment: @newacct, Take a look: https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/hk2testcase/src/ddfbb5ffab49a823dbc907b935b17667a97558f6/src/main/java/com/mycompany/hk2testcase/Main.java?at=default ... You're welcome to fork this and contribute back a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a cast is simply not safe *in general*, and the fact that it is safe for the `Class` class can not be detected. Imagine a class like this:

```
// Hypothetical!
class MyClass<T> extends Class<T> {
    public T someInstance;
}
```

Now, if the cast in question was allowed, you could do something like

```
MyClass<Integer> myClassWithInteger = new MyClass<Integer>();
myClassWithInteger.someInstance = someInteger;

// This is valid
MyClass<? extends Object> myClassWithWildcard = myClassWithInteger; 

// This is NOT valid, but let's assume it was:
MyClass<Object> myClassWithObject = myClassWithWildcard; 

// This would be valid, because 'someInstance' was of type 'Object' here
myClassWithObject.someInstance = "someString";

// This is valid. But through the unchecked cast, we silently
// sneaked in an STRING as this instance. So this would fail:
Integer i = myClassWithInteger.someInstance;
```

You asked in the comment:

> Are you saying that the language authors wanted to avoid special treatment for safe classes like Class so they forbid this across the board?

Yes. The crucial point is that the question whether such a cast is safe or not depends on the *semantics* of the class. The safety can not be detected *syntactically*.

Answer (score 0):

This can't fail indeed. But this is an generic warning for an upcast, regardless of its parameter.

You could use instead:

```
Class<? extends Object> clazz = String.class;
Class<?> clazzObject = clazz; // Does not generate Warning.
```

Comment: `<? extends Object>` and `<?>` mean the same thing, so your example doesn't actually demonstrate anything special :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to ensure a specific class of interface by using generics you should just use "?" instead of "? extends Object". The compiler assumes Object for every unbounded generic Parameter at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not saying it's illegal, it's saying it's unsafe and can lead to runtime errors.

Consider the following code:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> lf = li;
List<Number> ln = (List<Number>)lf;
ln.add(new Float(1.1));     
Integer value = li.get(0);
```

It'll fail on the last line because we snuck in a Float in that list of Integers through that unsafe case.