# Why do I get a warning when I cast X<? extends Item> to X<Item>?

Tags: java

I've got a class that implements an interface that declares a method with return type

```
X<Item>
```

and I'm calling another class with a method m() that is declared to return

```
X<? extends Item>
```

I try to return the result directly, by casting it:

```
return (X<Item>)other.m()
```

Why do I get a warning? What could possibly go wrong? Is there a way to do it that avoids the warning?

Comment: Basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212676/why-is-upcasting-a-class-considered-an-unsafe-operation , although this referred to `Class` instead of `X` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that might be an `X<SubItem>`, which is not an `X<Item>`.

What you're doing is inherently unsafe; the whole point of `X<? extends>` is that you *don't know* what the actual type parameter is.

If you're sure that it's actually an `X<Item>`, you can use the unsafe cast, and manually suppress the warning, since you know more than the compiler does.

If you aren't completely certain of that, your code is broken, and you need to rethink your types.

Answer (score 0):

That is because a `X<? extends Item>` is not a `X<Item>`.  The wildcard introduces the possibility that it could be any class that subclasses `Item` (or `Item` itself).  Java generics are not covariant; they are invariant.  So even if some subclass `SubItem` is an `Item`, any `X<SubItem>` is not a `X<Item>`.  That means that a `X<? extends Item>` is not a `X<Item>`.

To preserve type safety at compile time, the compiler must warn you of a potentially unsafe cast, and because of the above reasons, the cast is potentially unsafe, so it warns you with an "unchecked cast" warning.  Interestingly, you can cast a `X<Item>` to a `X<? extends Item>`, because that is in itself safe.

Comment: Followup questions: (a) I guess we are used to using casting to tell the compiler that we know something is safe although the compiler can't prove it, and this traditionally doesn't generate a warning; (b) what exactly do you mean by "is not a" in the above? The concern is with substitutability, and with a well-designed type hierarchy, List<Car> is going to be substitutable for List<Vehicle> if Car is subtitutable for Vehicle. So my original questions remain: what can actually go wrong, and how should I convert a `X<? extends Item>` to an `X<Item>` if casting won't do the job?

Comment: Answering one of my questions, I found this helpful: The warning is not just because the compiler does not know that the cast is safe. For example String s = (String) new Object() ; gets no warning, even though the compiler does not know that the cast is safe. The warning is because the compiler (a) does not know that the cast is safe AND (b) will not generate a complete run-time check at the point of the cast. There will be a check that it is a Hashmap, but there will not be a check that it is a HashMap<String,String>. –  Theodore Norvell Feb 28 '13 at 16:46